# passing objects into the url - Url Params /Query strings

Tags: query-string, url-parameters

I have two websites. One website is going to capture form data and put it into a url...

```
let url = `https://xxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/band/${band._id}?toggle=true&eventDate={"eventDate": ${mainDate[0]}, "eventCharge": ${mainDate[1]}}&quoteAdjuster=${sliderValue}`
```

Some of the information that I collect in the form is stored in objects and arrays.

Is there a way to send objects/arrays in this url to my website? Currently that whole object above, mainDate, still comes through as a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could change your objects and arrays into strings on purpose by using `JSON.stringify(myObject)`.

Then the server would just need to just use `JSON.parse(sentData)` in order to reconstruct the arrays and objects (some types of data don't survive this operation, so be careful. For example `Date` objects become strings and you have to reconstruct them manually).

Also, remember that the GET protocol has a [fairly small payload limit (8KB)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995). You will want to switch to using POST, if those parameters aren't important for the URL that the user is browsing.